# A problem with $RANDOM range in bash

Tags: bash

why the code below, supposed to display a random from 2-3 range, actually works as if the range was 2-4?

```
echo $((RANDOM%3+2))
```

Comment: Who supposes such thing? Interval length of 3 (range 0..2) and minimum value of 2 – that is 2..4 for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead if you want a reliable way :

```
intrandfromrange() { echo "$(( ( RANDOM % ($2 - $1 +1 ) ) + $1 ))"; }
intrandfromrange 2 4
```

Comment: No need double quotes around an integer Stephane =)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

- `RANDOM%3` has 3 possible values:

0, 1 and 2

+2 then:

2, 3 and 4